# SSL Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm developing a small discord bot that uses pymongo (MongoDB). When I run my code locally throws an error, when I run my code in VPS it works with no error I'm on windows 10.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yas_!_ru\Documents\GitHub\Mindustry Ranked\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    init_db()
  File "c:\Users\Yas_!_ru\Documents\GitHub\Mindustry Ranked\utils\DBUtils.py", line 113, in init_db
    DBUtils.settings = get_settings(DBUtils.db)
  File "c:\Users\Yas_!_ru\Documents\GitHub\Mindustry Ranked\utils\DBUtils.py", line 120, in get_settings
    db_settings = settings_collection.find({'name': 'production'}).next()
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1207, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1100, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1816, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1802, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 490, in get_server_session
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Yas_!_ru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-01.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129),cluster0-shard-00-02.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129),cluster0-shard-00-00.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60a39fb36200a62d85a9620b, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.mrf1p.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.mrf1p.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.mrf1p.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.mrf1p.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')>]>
```

[image: This is more readable]

Comment: do you have some sort of internet filtering software like netspark or somthing like that?

Comment: I have VPN but its not switched on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing this certificate solved the issue https://crt.sh/?id=4536904705

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to python package version differences between your VPS and your host system.

Maybe adding

> tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True

to your client definition may help removing the error

Answer (score 0):

For windows

import certifi

Add

'tlsCAFile': 'path\cacert.pem', in Client Section